# Connecting Through Remote Desktop Gateway

Tags: remote-desktop, gateways

From my laptop outside of office, I need to (RDP) connect to a server in the private subnet through remote desktop gateway (RDGW) server in public subnet. 
Here is my RDP setting on my laptop:

```
Gateway settings tab: 
Use a TS Gateway server: Checked
Server Name: Public IP address (54.21.24.11)
By pass for local addresses: Unchecked
Share Gateway .....: Checked and username, password and domain entered


Server Settings tab:
Server Name: Local IP address of server in private subnet (10.0.0.10)
```

It takes longer than normal to connect and at the end it errors out with message remote server is not accessible. User name, password and domain are all fine but somehow I can't get connected to 10.0.0.10.
Everything works if I first RDP to 54.21.24.11 and from there RDP to 10.0.0.10.

I did many different settings but the result is always failure in connection.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was due to the port 443 (HTTPS) being closed on the RDGW server. I opened the port and added a trusted certificate. Everything works now.